# Psyc - 295- stat method

Tags: statistics

Dave suspected that his hamster ate more than the average hamster (of the same breed) did. While the average hamster eats 900 g of food a day (SD=450), he monitored his hamsters for a month and found that his hamster ate 1,100 g of food a day (SD =530). Can he conclude that his hamster eats more than the average hamster? why?

I am not looking for the answer, just a little help. I am at a total loss with this, and I think it might be a trick question. I just need to be pointed in the right direction. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: At what level of confidence? It seems you want to test the one side hypothesis that $$H_0:\mu=\mu_{\text{your hamster}};H_1:\mu<\mu_{\text{your hamster}}$$?